# AngularJS: refresh ng-options when property source object changes

Tags: angularjs, ng-options, angularjs-ng-options

Full description:
I have list of options with multiple properties (not just key-value pair):

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "111",
    some: "qqq"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "222",
    some: "www"
  }
];
```

And select defined as:

```
<select name="mySelect" id="mySelect"
  ng-options="option.name for option in opts track by option.id"
  ng-model="mod1"></select>
```

Depending on app logic, extra property may change:

```
{
  id: 2,
  name: "222",
  some: "www1"
}
```

But actual list in Select doesn't change!
However, if name changes, then entire optionList will be refreshed.

In short you can see demo on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ydn52nx8/) OR [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ydn52nx8/3/). I prepared 2 very similar examples:

1. When button is clicked only extra property updates
2. When button is clicked - both extra property and key receive new value

Does anybody know solution?

## UPDATE

For now I'm solving that issue with `update + delay + update` solution:

```
this.click = function(){
  $scope.opts = {};
  $timeout(function() {
    $scope.opts = { /* NEW OBJECT */};
  }, 0);
}
```

Comment: this is discussed in detail on the documentation page: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions.  "Note that $watchCollection does a shallow comparison of the properties of the object (or the items in the collection if the model is an array). This means that changing a property deeper than the first level inside the object/collection will not trigger a re-rendering"

Comment: Hm, thanks for pointing out. I though "first level" means all properties, but not included objects, e.g. `{name: "111", id: 1, some: {name: "111-1", id: "1-1"}}`. So in this case changes of `some.name` should be ignored...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so I *think* I understand what you want, which is to be able to select an option whose nested values may have changed since the list was rendered in the DOM.

Based on that understanding, I believe that the plunker I have created illustrates a solution for you. If you select one of the options, and change the child value in the input field, two-way binding will update the model.

Basically, it is taking the users selection, and on select change, re-assigning the selected object to reference the original option in the options array. This will allow two-way binding to occur. If you view the code, you will see that the input fields are updating the option list itself (*$scope.options*), where-as the model that is being displayed is *$scope.formData.model*.

https://plnkr.co/edit/DLhI7t7XBw9EbIezBCjI?p=preview

**HTML**

```
<select 
  name="mySelect"
  id="mySelect"
  ng-model="formData.model"
  ng-change="onChange(formData.model)"
  ng-options="option.name for option in options track by option.id"></select>

  SELECTED CHILD: {{formData.model.child.name}}

<hr>

<div ng-repeat="option in options">
  Child Name for {{ option.name }}: <input ng-model="option.child.name">
</div>
```

**JS**

```
  $scope.onChange = function(option) {

    angular.forEach($scope.options,function(optionItem){
      if (optionItem.id == option.id){
         $scope.formData.model = optionItem;
      }
    })


  }

  $scope.options = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "111",
      child: {
        id: 11,
        name: "111-1"
      }
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "222",
      child: {
        id: 22,
        name: "222-1"
      }
    }
  ];

  $scope.formData = {
    model: $scope.options[0]
  };
```

Comment: I updated initial description: added new link to JSFiddle with more clear solution without nested objects. However your code is exactly what I have. And your solution almost works :) Thanks. Last issue that I still have: 1) Select option "222" 2) Update entire `$scope.options` collection (in example you update value in existing object), but I need to update full collection at once (from $http). As result `SELECTED CHILD` wouldn't update (still show old value). 3) But when you change value in select - your solution works again [fork](https://plnkr.co/edit/M0SiBs8rbhlIxio8VDxq?p=preview)

Comment: My bad... I just need to call `$scope.onChange($scope.formData.model);` from `click` method. Thanks for your solution. It just works and replace `track by option.id` statement... Now it is just redundant... Strange that angular doesn't do that

Answer (score 0):

Call `$apply` whenever you want to apply changes made.

```js
$scope.$apply();
```

This will tell AngularJS to refresh.

Comment: If your logic that affects the model executes asynchronously then yes this will be part of the solution.